# FFMpegConverter. ConvertLiveMedia method doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

I need to convert files from AWS cloud, which mounted like a local drive by using TntDrive. 
I tried to use `FFMpegConverter.ConvertMedia` method, but it works slow. In another question someone explained to me next:

"It looks like you need to use the `FFMpegConverter.ConvertLiveMedia` method instead of the FFMpegConverter.ConvertMedia method to achieve this. Overall you will still find that you will be probably I/O bound rather than CPU bound."

But next code didn't work for me:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input_path =
                @"D:\WAV\ALBUM1\UNDER_ALBUM1\APOV01_10 POV 8_MAIN.WAV";
            string dest_path = @"D:\result.mp3";
            using (FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(input_path, FileMode.Open))
            {

                var converter = new FFMpegConverter();

                var result = converter.ConvertLiveMedia(
                    inputStream, "WAV",
                    dest_path, "MP3",
                    new ConvertSettings
                    {
                        AudioSampleRate = 44100,
                        CustomOutputArgs = " -b:a 192k "
                    }
                    );
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ffMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(input_path, null, dest_path, "mp3", new ConvertSettings() {
 CustomOutputArgs = " -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -y -f mp3 -movflags faststart"
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.SE - having given the answer, perhaps you could explain the reasoning for it... if you like, the design documentation?

Comment: Documentation is here http://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.VideoConverter/

Answer (score -1):

You have to start the conversion I think...

```
result.Start();
```